# Get whole state object in pinia action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

How can I get whole state obejct(only the state "values" without actions) inside pinia action? "this" return whole store object.

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => ({
    count: 0,
    name: "apple",
    color: "green",
  }),
  actions: {
    myaction() {
      const wholeState = state?; // {count: 0, name: "apple", color: "green"}
      console.log(wholestate)'
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.$state`.
[Document](https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/pinia._StoreWithState.html#state)